Is there any way to create a dynamic route in nextjs to open link with query param?
I am trying to create a dynamic link using nextjs which will say that your account has been verified. The link for that page will be different for each user signs-up, and link looks something like this
localhost:3000/emailVerification?token=eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJlbWFpbCI6InJlY3J1aXRlckB0YWx
I am using [slug]/page.jsx to create a dynamic link. But it doesn't work for this kind of link.
Is there any way for this to work?
I am trying app/emailVerification/[emailVerification]/page.jsx folder structure.
I am expecting this route to open the url below
localhost:3000/emailVerification?token=eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJlbWFpbCI6InJlY3J1aXRlckB0YWx

To handle dynamic routes with query parameters in Next.js, you don't need to use the [slug] pattern in the file system for the query parameters directly. Instead, you should create a fixed route file and handle the query parameters within the component.
